# Wordpress WP_Query by jquery load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, include, load

i load by jquery a php file witch should load a new WP_Query,
but the WP load does not work, here my code:

the jquery code:

```
$('.teaser-click').click(function(){

var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
$("#content-"+post_id).load("xxxMYURLxxx/load-content.php", {neuId:post_id});

});
```

the load-content.php

```
$neuId = $_POST['neuId'];
echo "neuId: ".$neuId;
```

it works fine, till here, i get the right id,
and the ID alos shows up in the div, but i won't get
the content of the wp-query

i also tried 'p' => 200 (just for testing)

```
$args = array(
        'p' => $neuId,
        'post_type' => 'any',
);

$my_new_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_new_posts->have_posts()) : $my_new_posts->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

---

here is the wp query of the index file

```
if (have_posts()) : 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

...


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks, a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including  the file that defines WP_Query in your php file load-content?

please to send the whole load-content php file!

Comment: the answer of Robert Lee is the implementation of this.

Comment: yes, that was the mistake! here the code with worked for me!

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require_once('PATHHERE/wp-blog-header.php');

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

or if ABSPATH does not work you may want to try and manually use ../../ and go to the path.